# Auto scale up/down Cosmos DB RU's

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We experience throttling (429) due to burst of high traffic for a period of time. To mitigate this issue, we currently increase the RU in azure portal, and decrease it later.

I want to scale Up/Down based on the metrics, but, it does not expose the # of physical partitions created for the document DB container.

- How can I get the # of physical partitions for a document DB container?
- If someone in this group has solved auto scaling problem, I’m eager to know how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What to base the desired RU limit on

I would not go to physical partition level at all as the load probably does not distribute evenly across partitions anyway. I assume you probably don't care about average partition throughput but need to take care of the worst one.

So, if you need full auto-scale, then I would concentrate on tracking throttling events (occurs after the fact) or monitoring the total RU usage (partitioning magic). Both paths can go really complex to get true auto-scale and probably a combination of those would be needed. While upscaling seems achievable then deciding when to come back down and to what level is trickier.

It is hard to expect the unexpected and reliably react to things before they happen. Definitely consider if it's worth it in your scenario compared to simpler solutions.

#### Calendar-based RU limit baseline

An even simpler solution would be to just set the RU limit by a prepared schedule (i.e. weekday + time of day) following the average peak load trends.

This will not autoscale for unexpected peaks or fall-offs and would require some monitoring to adjust to the unexpected, but you have that anyway, right?
What such simple solution would give you, is a flexible throughput limit and predictable cost for the average day, with minimal effort.

#### Changing RU limit

Once you know WHAT RU limit you want at any given time, then executing it is easy. The increasing-decreasing or RU limit could be programmed and for example ran through [Azure functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/). C# example for actually changing the limit would be along the lines of:

```
var offer = client.CreateOfferQuery()
    .Where(r => r.ResourceLink == collection.SelfLink).Single();
offer = new OfferV2(offer, newthroughput);
client.ReplaceOfferAsync(offer);
```

Your Azure function could tick periodically and depending on your configured schedule or gathered events adjust the `newthroughput` accordingly.

#### A note of caution

Whatever autoscale solution you implement, do think about setting reasonable hard limits for how high you are willing to go. Otherwise you could get unexpected bills from Azure in case of mishaps or malicious activity(DDOS). Having throttling is better at some point.

Comment: Actually, you just want the database/collection to autoscale it's throughput. Am I right?  if so, vote here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/16598674-autoscale-throughput-ur-s

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/giorgited/CosmosScale

I wrote this library to help the with autoscaling. We were using azure functions to do the scaling in the morning and scale back down at night but realized that it was not as efficient.

The above mentioned library will scale up to the maximum of the desired RU provided by the user and scale back down when there is no inactivity. It handles bulk operations differently then single operations, see the github for the full info, including the benchmark stats.

**Disclaimer**: I am an author of this library.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more up-to-date answer for this now (as of 2019-11-19): The "Auto Pilot" feature (currently in Preview) performs scale-up and scale-down automatically.

At the time of writing this can be found in the "Preview Features" blade for the Cosmos DB account on the Azure Portal. It will obviously move once it comes out of preview. The most up to date instructions should be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/provision-throughput-autopilot

Comment: Note that it's only for new collections, and that autopilot RUs cost 50% more than regular ones.

Comment: @Malt Good points. I had thought that it would scale down to below the minimum 400RUs (which would be good for occasional use and offset the price difference) but I cannot now find any evidence of this.

Answer (score 0):

Autoscale is now GA with serverless coming in preview. More details: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/autoscale-serverless-offers/